# Looking for an Over-the-Air HD tuner compatible with Windows Media Center

Tags: windows-media-center, product-rec, tuner-card

For Over-the-Air HD signals, what is the best TV tuner for use with Windows Media Center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I purchased the [HDHomeRun Networked Digital TV Tuner](http://www.silicondust.com/products/hdhomerun_atsc) and we'll see how well it works with Windows Media Center.

Comment: I love mine. I got the one with two tuners and it's perfectly capable of recording two shows at once while I'm watching something on my TV.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend an internal tuner, but if it must be USB the [AVerMedia](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815100035) is cheap, small and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I had a [DViCo Fusion nano](http://www.fusionhdtv.co.kr/ENG/products/DVBTNanoPlus.aspx) and it was a great unit until it suddenly died. I replaced it with two [Pinnacle PCTV USB HD Sticks](http://www.pinnaclesys.com/) and they work great, but I notice that they have just sold that business.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the ASUS PE9400. This is the cheapest I could find with good HD features.